# Union parameters with TypeScript 1.4

Tags: typescript1.4

I have some troubles using union parameters. Imagine I have such a function:

```
interface IColumnDefinition {
    id: string;
    title: string;
}

addColumn(definition: string|IColumnDefinition) {
    if (typeof (definition) === "string") {
        definition = { id: definition, title: definition };
    }

    var column = new JSColumn(definition);
    ...
}
```

I want the user to either pass a complete object that defines a new column, or just pass a `string`, in which case I create a default object.

However, TypeScript has 2 problems:

- `definition = { id: definition };` is not allowed, since TypeScript thinks that `definition` might not be a string - which is wrong, since I make a `typeof` one line above.
- `new JSColumn(definition)` is not possible, since the constructor requires a `IColumnDefinition` object, and `definition` could also be a string - which is also wrong, because the `if` above made sure that it is always a correct object.

What can I do to convince TypeScript that these are not errors? Is there anything like a cast, which says *"Hey, this variable is of type `xyz`. Trust me, I know what I do."*

I'm currently defining the parameter as `any`, which isn't really an option as I lose the whole advantage of type-checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to circumvent the type system of TypeScript you can always use `<any>` cast.

In this case however there's a better solution:

```
function addColumn(definition: string | IColumnDefinition) {
    var colDef: IColumnDefinition;
    if (typeof definition === "string") {
        colDef = { id: definition, title: definition };
    } else {
        colDef = definition;
    }

    var column = new JSColumn(colDef);
    // ...
}
```

Another option, which might be less clear but generates a smaller JS code:

```
function addColumn(definition: string | IColumnDefinition) {
    var column = new JSColumn(
        (typeof definition === "string")
            ? { id: definition, title: definition }
            : definition);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work since the two `colDef` assignements are not allowed. The first one says `Type '{ id: string | IColumnDefinition; }' is not assignable to type 'IColumnDefinition'.`, while the second one throws `Type 'string | IColumnDefinition' is not assignable to type 'IColumnDefinition'`.

Comment: However, I combined it with your other suggestion - `colDef = <any>{ id: definition };` seems to work.

Comment: @maja Are you sure that you've copied the code over correctly? The code I posted compiles with no warnings or errors for me.

Comment: WOW, it works if I remove the brackets around `typedef`

Comment: I'm still wondering if it is possible to tell TypeScript that a specific variable actually has a different type, which might be very usable in some situations.

Comment: @maja You can't change the type of a variable after declaration, but you can achieve this by declaring another variable. For example: `var s: string = "lupus"; var x: number = <any> s;`

Comment: Although I don't like that solution (the resulting JavaScript code is bigger), it works good enough. Thanks, that helped me a lot.

Comment: @maja I've edited my answer to include a version which generates a smaller JS code.